# How can the preterite in the second clause place its event BEFORE that of the past perfect’s event in the first clause?

Tags: past-perfect, sequence-of-tenses, narration

Here the chronology seems inverted as regards to the proper use of the past
perfect and the preterite to order two different events that both occurred
in the past:

- He **had not been**<sup>[*past perfect*]</sup> happy with Sally
   since she
  **mentioned**<sup>[*preterite*]</sup> the lost purse.

Chronologically, the mention of the lost purse comes first.  Do you agree
that the preterite *since she mentioned* is correct, though? I do not need to write *since she **had** mentioned the lost purse*, do I?

How can the past perfect **ever** come ***after*** the preterite?
Isn’t the entire reason for using these two contrasting constructions
together so that the past perfect places one event further in the past than
the preterite places other event?

How come you can invert the required sequence of tenses like this without
breaking the time-ordering and confusing people?

Comment: What's the full context?

Comment: Because English is perverse? More specifically, my intuition as a native speaker says that you don't need to use the past perfect in clauses with time prepositions like "since" and "when", even if the action occurs before the action in the main sentence; I don't have any idea *why* this is true; I don't think you could get away with it in French.

Comment: @PeterShor It's because it's a present perfect in the past. In other words it is a state that started before the time in the past that we're thinking about and it's still ongoing then. If the person had been speaking then he would have said "I haven't been happy with Sally since she lost the purse".

Comment: _She having mentioned the lost purse, thereafter he had not been happy with Sally_. Up-voted +1.

Comment: He has not been happy since 2:00 pm.

Answer (score 2):

His not being happy continued from a point in the past (T1), specified by her mentioning the lost purse, up until another time in the past, which we assume is the time the narration is referring to in the main clause (T2), a situation which calls for the preterite perfect. Her mentioning the lost purse is simply used to denote a point in time, and hence does not call for the preterite perfect as: (a) there is no current relevance to T2 and (b) it was a punctive event that did not continue in between T1 and T2. There is no relevance as the relation between her mentioning the lost purse and him not being happy with her is purely circumstantial - there is no direct causal link between the two, only temporal.

Compare with:

> Since she had only completed two of the projects, we were forced to
> fire her.

where the situation introduced by *since* clearly has relevance to a punctive situation expressed in the main clause, or

> He had been unhappy with her since she had been in his employ.

where the preterite perfect makes sense as the situation expressed by the clause introduced by *since* lasted for a period time up to the point of past narration.